# How to create ReadOnly user in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

Is it possible to create a user in ActiveAdmin that is readonly (they can open all entries, etc but can't make changes to them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Ryan Bates Cancan gem for this, see this - [for implementation instructions](https://gist.github.com/1264060)

Robbie

Answer (score 1):

[There's an open issue on this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/355). At this point, you'll have to mess with the source code though.